# How to make rsync to use relative path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

I want to sync remote database copy using command

```
rsync --relative user@remote:/backup/databases/*.sql /backup/snapshots/
```

As it's result command creates file `/backup/snapshots/backup/databases/mysql.sql`. How can I force it to put file in `/backup/snapshots/mysql.sql`? It's mandatory that source must be remote (it's part of more complex script).

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/552120/preserve-directory-tree-while-copying-with-rsync

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you **don't** want to use the `--relative` flag, as this creates subdirectories in the target location. Have you tried this?

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

```
 -R, --relative              use relative path names
```

Answer (score 5):

What about passing rsync the --no-relative option?

Comment: Thank you for `--no-relative`